# searchPattern Logic on Directory.GetFiles Method

Tags: c#, .net, search

I would like to know what is the search pattern logic on Directory.GetFiles Method. I use asterisk wildcard on my search pattern. I do not understand what kind of logic to apply on searching if i put "*" in-front of char.

I got unexpected result if i put "*" in-front of char but it was correct if i put at behind of char.

Here is file list in folder, sample code and result.

[image]

Asterisk in-front of char

```
string _strSearchPattern = "*1";
foreach (string _strFolder in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp\FileList", _strSearchPattern))
Console.WriteLine("{0}", _strFolder);
```

Unexpected result. It should be 1. Why "b_Request" is come out but why not "b" is include?

[image]

Asterisk behind of char

```
string _strSearchPattern = "1*";
foreach (string _strFolder in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp\FileList", _strSearchPattern))
Console.WriteLine("{0}", _strFolder);
```

Here is expected result

[image]

Is it bug or i'm thinking too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is sort of tricky but not a bug.

Asterisk (*) stands for zero or more characters in that position and question mark (?) stands for zero or one character in that position.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Because this method checks against file names with both the 8.3 file
>   name format and the long file name format, a search pattern similar to
>   "*1*.txt" may return unexpected file names. For example, using a
>   search pattern of "*1*.txt" returns "longfilename.txt" because the
>   equivalent 8.3 file name format is "LONGFI~1.TXT".

In you first case, a search path with "*1" will match any path ends with letter 1, path 1 and path b_Request (with the 8.3 file name format b_Requ~1) will be returned.

You can refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) for more about 8.3 filename.

Comment: Thanks! As you said "b_Request" (with the 8.3 file name format "b_Requ~1) and match with search pattern, it was clear my doubt. I saw "B_REQU~1" if i check with "dir /x" or "dir /-n". How about the "b_1"? Is it under "8.3 format"? I do not see anything shortfile format in dir list. Can you provide me some information again.

Comment: @yukon, from the wikipedia link, it says "8.3 filenames are limited to at most eight characters", so my understanding is that for file path with length smaller than or equal to 8, 8.3 file name format does not apply to them. Hope it helps.